# how to continues looping until user hits"enter" without first typing a name

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class lab5c
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
String name;
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
name=input.nextLine();

if (name.startsWith( "Liyana" ) || name.startsWith( "Batrisyia" ) || name.startsWith( "Arfa" )  )
System.out.println( "Ms. "+name );
else
System.out.println( "Mr. "+name );

}
}
```

how to continues looping the program until the user hits "enter" without first typing a name.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the String is empty, something like this:

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    String name = "default";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
    while(!name.isEmpty()){
        name=input.nextLine();

        if (name.startsWith( "Liyana" ) || name.startsWith( "Batrisyia" ) || name.startsWith( "Arfa" )  ){
            System.out.println( "Ms. "+name );
        }else{
            System.out.println( "Mr. "+name );
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if name.length() <= 0 then you can exit.

Comment: but why if i press enter , the word "mr." still display??

Answer (score 0):

```
while(name.isEmpty()){
    System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
name=input.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
while ((name = input.nextLine()).length() > 0)  
{  
   . . .   
}
```